# Electron - listen to 'menu-will-show' event

Tags: events, menu, electron

Environment:

- OS: Ubuntu Cosmic (18.10)
- Electronjs: 4.0.5

---

The Electron docs indicate there are two events on the menu instance:

- 'menu-will-show'
- 'menu-will-close'

The docs do not, however, indicate how to register a listener on the menu instance for an event.

On my main application menu (instantiated with Menu.buildFromTemplate, and
set with Menu.setApplicationMenu) I have tried variations of the following on the menu instance returned from buildFromTemplate:

- menu.addListener('menu-will-show', ()=>{})
- menu.addEventListener('menu-will-show', ()=>{})
- menu.on('menu-will-show', ()=>{})
- (each of the above specifying the class rather than the instance)
- (each of the above specifying the object returned by Menu.getAppliationMenu (in case the menu object I sent is destroyed on *set*, or otherwise thrown away)

None of them are triggering.

The docs say some events don't work on some operating systems where specified, but there is no additional information on the event documentation suggesting that linux doesn't work.

The intent is to check and set menu item state before the menu is shown.

I can brute force setting the item state another way, but would rather use this mechanism, if possible.

I'll try on Windows and OSX, eventually, but on Linux, it's not happening.

Answer (score 0):

This event triggers when `menu.popup()` is programmatically called:

> Emitted when menu.popup() is called.

Source: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/menu#event-menu-will-show

Here's an example:

This is my main thread. It creates a menu and calls `menu.popup` every seconds. So I should be seeing in the console.

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, Menu} = require('electron');
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');

app.on('ready', () => {
  const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    {
      role: 'help',
      submenu: [
        {label: 'Order a burrito'}
      ]
    }
  ]);
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
  menu.addListener('menu-will-show', () => {
    console.log('');
  });

  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});
  mainWindow.loadURL(
    url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
      protocol: 'file:',
      slashes: true
    })
  );

  setInterval(()=> {
    menu.popup({window: mainWindow});
  }, 1000);

});
```

As you can see in this screencast, the `menu.popup()` call makes a context menu appear which in turn prints out a burrito into the console:

[image]

Comment: That seems to be for a context menu.  A main menu is not programmatically triggered to pop-up - it's popped up by a click on the menu bar.  Does electron not emit the 'menu-will-show' event under that circumstance?  Is there an event I *can* capture when a main menu is popped up by a click on the menubar?